# Angular 2+ and Entity Framework :Cannot get objects by Id, returns an empty array

Tags: angular, entity-framework, httprequest

I have problems with getting Wall objects where attribute userID is equal to parameter which I get from another HTTP request. Request for fetching all walls is successful, but when I pass the userID, it returns an empty array. I am using Entity Framework as backend. I have tested the request in Postman and it works.

Controller :

```
[HttpGet("GetWallsByUserId/{userId}")]
       public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Wall>>> GetWallsByUserId(string userId) 
       {
           return await _context.Walls.Where(w => w.userID == userId).ToListAsync();
       }
```

Service code :

```
getQuizByUserId(id:any){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.BaseURI+'/Wall/GetWallsByUserId/'+id).pipe(
      catchError(Error=>of(null))
    );
```

In component I am getting the Id of current logged user and I am passing that id to get all the Wall objects with that Id :

```
userID:any;
userDetails;
walls=[];
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
     res=>{
       this.userDetails=res;
        this.userID=this.userDetails.id;
        console.log(this.userID);
     }
   );
     this.service.getQuizByUserId(this.userID).subscribe(
       res=>{
         this.walls=res;
         console.log(res);
       }
     )
}

}
```

I really dont know what I am missing, in console userId is always successfully returned but res and walls is always empty array. Here is sucessful request of getting all walls :

```
 getAllWalls()//getting all the wall in home component
  {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.BaseURI+'/Wall');
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c# code is syncrhonious while javascript is asynchronious. you get `this.userId` TOO LATE. if you debug your code you will see that `this.service.getQuizByUserId(this.userID)` is called with undefined, rather than userId. To fix that try to use rxjs in a right way. possible solution:

```
  this.userService.getUserProfile().pipe(
     switchMap(res => {
       this.userDetails = res;
       this.userID = this.userDetails.id;
       return this.service.getQuizByUserId(this.userID)
     })
  ).subscribe(res => {
      this.walls = res;
      console.log(res);
   })
```

Comment: I figured I was not sending that Id properly and that my approach might be wrong. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

When you sub your service ts doesn’t wait response it continues to executing other codes. After your service recieve data then    res=>{} block runs.

Call this code block before console.log(this.userID). You can make it a function and call before console.log(this.userID)

```
this.service.getQuizByUserId(this.userID).subscribe(
   res=>{
     this.walls=res;
     console.log(res);
   }
 )
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your `pipe` you should also `map` the content, like this:

```js
getQuizByUserId(id:any){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.BaseURI+'/Wall/GetWallsByUserId/'+id).pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
        return res;
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => { return throwError(error); })
    );
```